# Generating unique download link to download once only

Tags: php, http

I wanna create a few unique download link for my users. The reason is that I wanted to let them download once only, so that they can use back the same link to download again.

I've generate a few of the keys (example, qwertyasdfghzxcbn. As in the download link will be like www.xxxxx.com/download.php?qwertyasdfghzxcbn) in the database and flag field where when the user downloaded, it will update 1 to the flag field.

I did a search on the net and found this.
http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/creating-one-time-download-links/

But that only works when you go to the page first then only the page will generate the unique link. I've already pre-generate the link inside my database, I don't need to regenerate again, if fact if I generate the key when user go the page, they will able to download multiple times by refreshing the page.

Comment: I've just woke up, but where is the problem exactly? Why do you want to track them to download just once? Many systems are using link lifetime, so they don't spam the database if not needed and they try to avoid php/database often if files are bigger or there are lots of files. My website works as follows: user refreshes page, unique link is generated with unique hashes static word+time, starts downloading active_downloads is flagged in the DB, user downloads or cancels file, server removes the file from active_downloads. Link lifetime is 5 mins, nowhere is stored hashed key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution would be to make the link target itself a PHP script.

You'd hide the actual file somewhere inaccessible from the browser (i.e., somewhere where you can reach the file via `fopen()`, but isn't within the document root), and put a download.php file to download files.

The download script itself would look something like this:

```
$fileid = $_REQUEST['file'];
$file = file_location($fileid); // you'd write this function somehow
if ($file === null) die("The file doesn't exist");
$allowed = check_permissions_for($file, $fileid) // again, write this
// the previous line would allow you to implement arbitrary checks on the file
if ($allowed) {
  mark_downloaded($fileid, $file); // so you mark it as downloaded if it's single-use
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); // downloadable file
  echo file_get_contents($file);
  return 0; // running a return 0; from outside any function ends the script
} else
  die("You're not allowed to download this file");
```

Any link you point would simply point to download.php?fileid=712984 (whatever the fileid actually is). That would be the actual download link, since that script does transfer the file; but only if the user is allowed to retrieve it. You'd have to write the `file_location()`, `check_permissions_for()` and `mark_downloaded()` functions yourself though.

Comment: `readfile()`, not `echo file_get_contents()`. Even better would be mod_xsendfile for Apache. Unless you really like wasting resources by reading files into memory.

Comment: @deceze I wrote a 20-second implementation, didn't go and look through all the ways to read and send a file. I believe you your function is better there, so thanks for the info!

Comment: I sort of get the idea now. But I'm still an amateur in php world, do you have some step by step guide or tutorial?

Comment: @AdamSmith Not really, I just wrote that code on the fly. But try a few things, try to get it to work, and ask again if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using uniqid() function, and store unique ids with the expiration date in a database, while returning to the user url with something like this: ...?file_id=$id

When the link is being opened, you may delete it from the database or mark it to be deleted 'soon' (just in case user wants to refresh the page.)

Comment: Do you have any guides on how to do it? I have no idea at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here for the uniqid() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: As per database, Use mysql. There can be learning curve, of course.